# How to specify lifetime for associated type that will be a closure argument?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a trait with a function, and this function takes a closure as an argument, and *that closure* takes an argument that needs to be some type implementing the `Read` trait:

```
trait CanRead {
    type Reader: io::Read;
    
    fn do_reading<F>(&mut self, fun: F)
    where F: FnOnce(&mut Self::Reader);
}
```

I can easily implement this trait for anything which already implements `Read`, by specifying `type Reader = Self;` and just running `fun(self);` in the `do_reading` function.

The challenge is, I want to also implement this trait for some type which must make a temporary vector of `u8`s. Then the associated type `Reader` needs to be a reference type, but I don't know what lifetime to give it:

```
pub struct EmptyStruct { }

impl CanRead for EmptyStruct {
    type Reader = &[u8]; // doesn't compile; must specify a lifetime here
    
    fn do_reading<F>(&mut self, fun: F)
    where F: FnOnce(&mut Self::Reader) {
        let temp = vec![1, 2, 3];
        fun(&mut &temp[..]);
    }
}
```

I know that I need to specify a lifetime, but what could it be? I looked at [this helpful related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734640/how-do-i-specify-lifetime-parameters-in-an-associated-type), but neither suggested approach works. The problem is that the lifetime of the `Reader` type actually has nothing to do with the lifetime of the `EmptyStruct` instance; instead, the `Reader` reference type just needs to *not outlive* the call to the closure itself. Is there some way to specify this in Rust, or another way to tackle this pattern?

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6b9a5c67fef029cfee30f58df1a6268c) has what I tried and didn't work.

(Note, I know for this specific code the `temp` vector could be replaced by a static array, but that won't work for what I really need to do.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, unfortunately you can't yet. The [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734640/how-do-i-specify-lifetime-parameters-in-an-associated-type) answer noted a GAT which will be a solution (as soon as it implemented). [Here's](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1598-generic_associated_types.md) an rfc (and [tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265)) what covers that case.

Comment: Thanks - I agree GAT will solve this problem in the future, but your answer doesn't give any help for what to do about this issue in code I am writing today. Perhaps a better way to phrase my question is, "what is the best work-around until GAT is implemented?"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current work-around. I hope that someone answers with a better solution than this!

A work-around is to use dynamic dispatch, avoiding the associated type entirely, like so:

```
pub trait CanRead {
    fn do_reading<F>(&mut self, fun: F)
    where F: FnOnce(&mut dyn io::Read);
}

pub struct EmptyStruct { }

impl CanRead for EmptyStruct {
    fn do_reading<F>(&mut self, fun: F)
    where F: FnOnce(&mut dyn io::Read) {
        let temp = vec![1, 2, 3];
        fun(&mut &temp[..]);
    }
}
```

The downside here is that, because the closure's access is through a `&mut dyn` reference, you lose some run-time efficiency because of [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch). Granted, the penalty is probably not too large, but it would be better to use Rust's powerful type system and generics to avoid this if possible.