# Lifetime mismatch in generic trait with iterator bound

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I'm trying to abstract an interface to a map-type backing data structure (currently `std::collections::HashMap` and `std::collections::BTreeMap`) so that I can swap out the data structure without affecting the calling code. I'm running into a lifetime error with one particular method: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=56b5ce84eb7d44cfaefbc1814d501eaf))

```rust
use std::collections::hash_map::{HashMap, Keys};

pub trait GroupedCollection<K, V, KeyIterator>
where
    KeyIterator: Iterator
{
    fn keys(&self) -> KeyIterator;
}

impl<K, V> GroupedCollection<K, V, Keys<'_, K, Vec<V>>> for HashMap<K, Vec<V>>
{
    fn keys(&self) -> Keys<'_, K, Vec<V>> {
        HashMap::keys(&self)
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The compiler's telling me I have a lifetime mismatch:

```
error: `impl` item signature doesn't match `trait` item signature
  --> src/main.rs:12:5
   |
7  |     fn keys(&self) -> KeyIterator;
   |     ------------------------------ expected `fn(&'1 HashMap<K, Vec<V>>) -> std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'2, K, Vec<V>>`
...
12 |     fn keys(&self) -> Keys<'_, K, Vec<V>> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ found `fn(&'1 HashMap<K, Vec<V>>) -> std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'1, K, Vec<V>>`
   |
   = note: expected `fn(&'1 HashMap<K, Vec<V>>) -> std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'2, K, Vec<V>>`
              found `fn(&'1 HashMap<K, Vec<V>>) -> std::collections::hash_map::Keys<'1, K, Vec<V>>`
help: the lifetime requirements from the `impl` do not correspond to the requirements in the `trait`
  --> src/main.rs:7:23
   |
7  |     fn keys(&self) -> KeyIterator;
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ consider borrowing this type parameter in the trait
```

I haven't worked much with the reserved lifetime `'_`. From reading [The Rust Reference: Lifetime Elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html), if I understand correctly (and I'm not sure that I do), the following applies:

> ## Default Trait Object Lifetimes
>
> ...
>
> If the trait object is used as a type argument of a generic type then the containing type is first used to try to infer a bound.
>
> - If there is a unique bound from the containing type then that is the default
>
> ...

My understanding is that this is where the compiler is deriving `'1` for both lifetime parameters on the `impl` signature.

Since I haven't given the compiler any information about lifetimes in my trait definition, my understanding is that the compiler assumes that the `&self` in `fn keys()` and `type Item = &'a K` in the monomorphized `hash_map::Keys` will have different lifetimes.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734640/how-do-i-specify-lifetime-parameters-in-an-associated-type), I *think* I might have arrived at the right solution, but it's melting my brain  a bit: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8ebeb8e39e99b1f4937a348cf27fda91))

```rust
use std::collections::hash_map::{HashMap, Keys};

pub trait GroupedCollection<'a, K: 'a, V, KeyIterator>
where
    KeyIterator: Iterator<Item = &'a K>,
{
    fn keys(&'a self) -> KeyIterator;
}

impl<'a, K, V> GroupedCollection<'a, K, V, Keys<'a, K, Vec<V>>> for HashMap<K, Vec<V>>
{
    fn keys(&'a self) -> Keys<K, Vec<V>> {
        HashMap::keys(&self)
    }
}
```

Am I understanding the problem correctly? And is adding the explicit lifetime `'a` the right solution here, or have I done something silly that happened to compile?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but a solution like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2168f1f09972d7a3604027f692a9677c) may be more appropriate depending on requirements not mentioned in your question.

Comment: I think `KeyIterator` would make more sense as an associated type instead of a type parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a lifetime of `'_` it means: "here I should write a lifetime, but I don't particularly care about it, so... whatever".

In particular, when you write it in a trait impl such as:

```
impl<K, V> GroupedCollection<K, V, Keys<'_, K, Vec<V>>> for ...
```

it is as if you wrote:

```
impl<'x, K, V> GroupedCollection<K, V, Keys<'x, K, Vec<V>>> for ...
```

That is, the users of this impl can instantiate it with any lifetime they want.

But when you write it in the return type of a function such as:

```
fn keys(&self) -> Keys<'_, K, Vec<V>>
```

is is as if you wrote:

```
fn keys<'s>(&'s self) -> Keys<'s, K, Vec<V>>
```

That is, the lifetime is deduced by the default lifetime rules.

Now, your first compiler error happens because your `Keys<'x, _, _>` from the trait argument and your `Keys<'s, _, _>` are not the same, so the type of the function `keys()` does not match the trait definition.

How to fix it? Well, your implementation of `keys` must return a value with its lifetime limited to that of `self`, so if you are willing to change the trait to reflect that:

```
pub trait GroupedCollection<'a, K, V, KeyIterator: 'a> {
    fn keys(&'a self) -> KeyIterator;
}

impl<'a, K, V> GroupedCollection<'a, K, V, Keys<'a, K, Vec<V>>> for HashMap<K, Vec<V>>
{
    fn keys(&'a self) -> Keys<'a, K, Vec<V>> {
        HashMap::keys(&self)
    }
}
```

Which is almost what you wrote in your second version (I think that you added a few unneeded constraints).

---

Following the comment by @cdhowie above, what you really want is a *Generic Associated Type* (GAT). This means that it is the implementation of the trait that decides the lifetime, not the user. Unfortunately they are still unstable:

```
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

use std::collections::hash_map::{HashMap, Keys};

pub trait GroupedCollection<K, V>
{
    type KeyIterator<'s> where Self: 's;
    fn keys<'s>(&'s self) -> Self::KeyIterator<'s>;
}

impl<K, V> GroupedCollection<K, V> for HashMap<K, Vec<V>>
{
    type KeyIterator<'s> = Keys<'s, K, Vec<V>>
        where Self: 's;
    fn keys<'s>(&'s self) -> Keys<'s, K, Vec<V>> {
        HashMap::keys(&self)
    }
}
```

Which I think it is much easier to understand and easier to use.

Comment: That's the clearest explanation of `'_` I've ever seen, and I checked a lot of books, references, etc. before posting. I finally feel like I get it. Thank you very much!