# Lifetime issue with generic trait bound

Tags: generics, rust, iterator, traits

I'm writing a trait as an interface over map-type data structures (e.g. `std::collections::BTreeMap` and `std::collections::HashMap`). This is a follow-up to a [question I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114666/lifetime-mismatch-in-generic-trait-with-iterator-bound), though it stands on its own.

I'm having a lifetime issue I can't seem to understand. I've searched for answers in all my textbooks, The Rust Reference, StackOverflow, and more, and I haven't been able to figure out what's going on. I've written almost a dozen variants on the following code based on the suggestions from the previous question, and I wind up with the same situation. **I'm hoping someone can help me understand either why `gc3()` is impossible or what I'm doing wrong.** I know it's entirely possible I've had my nose in the problem for so long I'm missing something simple that should be obvious. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78a741a3ceb61f19a1d4b882c95f3c94))

```rust
use std::collections::hash_map::{HashMap, Iter};

fn main() {
    gc1(&HashMap::new());
    gc2(&HashMap::new());
    gc3(HashMap::new());
}

// Works
fn gc1<'a>(map: &'a dyn GroupedCollection<'a, usize, usize, Iter<'a, usize, Vec<usize>>>) {
    let _ = map.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
}

// Works
fn gc2<'a, M>(map: &'a M)
where
    M: 'a + GroupedCollection<'a, usize, usize, Iter<'a, usize, Vec<usize>>>,
{
    let _ = map.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
}

// Compiler error: `map` does not live long enough
fn gc3<'a, M>(map: M)
where
    M: 'a + GroupedCollection<'a, usize, usize, Iter<'a, usize, Vec<usize>>>,
{
    let _ = map.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
}

pub trait GroupedCollection<'a, K, V, I: 'a> {
    fn iter(&'a self) -> I;
}

impl<'a, K, V> GroupedCollection<'a, K, V, Iter<'a, K, Vec<V>>> for HashMap<K, Vec<V>>
{
    fn iter(&'a self) -> Iter<'a, K, Vec<V>> {
        HashMap::iter(&self)
    }
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `map` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:27:13
   |
23 | fn gc3<'a, M>(map: M)
   |        -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
27 |     let _ = map.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             borrowed value does not live long enough
   |             argument requires that `map` is borrowed for `'a`
28 | }
   | - `map` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Is the compiler complaining because the references produced by `map.iter()` are dropped at the end of `collect()` because `collect(self)` consumes the iterator? (I've tried addressing this by assigning `'a: 'b` to `GroupedCollection` and `'b` to iterator references, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3efe34e8d41ee4e7df446d19deb42fbc))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Don't use a lifetime parameter, use HRTB: `where M: for<'a> GroupedCollection<'a, usize, usize, Iter<'a, usize, Vec<usize>>>`.

---

`'a` is a caller-chosen lifetime. Suppose the caller choose `'static` (in general, it is good to validate lifetimes against `'static`). `map.iter()` is desugared to `<M as GroupedCollection<'static, ...>>::iter(&map)`. `<M as GroupedCollection<'static, ...>>::iter()` requires `&'a self`, i.e. `&'static self`. But `map` is a local variable, and thus `&map` is definitely *not* `'static`. Boom.

It works with references because the caller not only choose `'a`, it also needs to provide a reference that matches it. If it'll choose `'static`, it will have to provide `&'static M` and so everything is fine.

The solution? You want a *callee*-chosen lifetime. That is, `M` implements `GroupedCollection` for some lifetime `'a` I choose, not my caller. There is no way to express that in Rust, but you can say "`M` implements `GroupedCollection` for *any* lifetime", and obviously that includes the lifetime I will choose. This is [Higher-Ranked Trait Bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html): `M: for<'a> GroupedCollection<'a, ...>`. So:

```rust
fn gc3<M>(map: M)
where
    M: for<'a> GroupedCollection<'a, usize, usize, Iter<'a, usize, Vec<usize>>>,
{
    // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4b4f4779601ea2e54e1bffa6e1e9473c).

Is it perfect? No. There may be cases where `M` doesn't implement `GroupedCollection` for *any* lifetime, but it does for the lifetime we choose. But you cannot do better without GAT.