# Implementing a trait function that returns generic

Tags: rust, traits

In the following code, the trait called LimitCollection has a function that returns a type that implements Iterator trait.

```rust
struct Limit {}

impl Limit {
    fn is_violated(&self) -> bool {
        todo!()
    }
}

trait LimitCollection {
    fn get_violated_limits<'a, I>(&'a self) -> I
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = &'a Limit>;
}
```

Now I'd like to make something that implements the trait but the compiler complains that there is mismatch between the type that I return and the generic return type: "expected type parameter `I`, found struct `Filter`"

```rust
struct ConcreteLimitCollection {
    limits: Vec<Limit>,
}

impl LimitCollection for ConcreteLimitCollection {
    fn get_violated_limits<'a, I>(&'a self) -> I
    where
        I: Iterator<Item = &'a Limit>,
    {
        self.limits.iter().filter(Limit::is_violated)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this construct work, preferably without resorting to dynamic allocation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you would use an associated type , in this case we would have some lifetimes involved (we need a GAT, generic associated type). Sadly what it is needed is not stabilized yet:

```rust
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

struct Limit {}

impl Limit {
    fn is_violated(&self) -> bool {
        todo!()
    }
}

trait LimitCollection {
    type Output<'a>: Iterator<Item = &'a Limit> where Self: 'a;
    fn get_violated_limits<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Output<'a>;
}

struct ConcreteLimitCollection {
    limits: Vec<Limit>,
}

impl LimitCollection for ConcreteLimitCollection {
    type Output<'a> = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a Limit> + 'a> where Self: 'a;
    
    fn get_violated_limits<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Output<'a> {
        Box::new(self.limits.iter().filter(|l| l.is_violated()))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=abc50c0f348e45f31fdd4f523595b5ff)

Disclaimer, I used `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a Limit> + 'a>` even if you did not wanted to use dinamic allocation, but in this case you would just have to fulfill the whole `Filter<...>` type. Just did used a Boxed iterator for the example simplicity.

@SvenMarnach fitted the types
:

```rust
impl LimitCollection for ConcreteLimitCollection {
    type Output<'a> = std::iter::Filter<std::slice::Iter<'a, Limit>, fn(&&Limit) -> bool>;
    
    fn get_violated_limits<'a>(&'a self) -> Self::Output<'a> {
        self.limits.iter().filter(|l| l.is_violated())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6116bf39a33ca45b80d538f50720f38a)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to fully specify the type in this case.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yeah, it would be complicated and convoluted saying the least.

Comment: It's not actually that complicated – I think the type could be described as `Filter<slice::Iter<'a, Limit>, fn(&Limit) -> bool>` – but I think you will hit some limit of the type system here.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yes, would need some lifetimes magic fit, not sure how to do it actually:  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b49f85eacfa377937c3bfe8cd02e1a9

Comment: The `'a` lifetime is definitely wrong for the function parameter. It should be `for<'r> fn(&'r Limit) -> bool`, which is actually the same as `fn(&Limit) -> bool` due to lifetime elision rules. However, that doesn't compile either, which may be due to one of the remaining bugs in GATs.

Comment: @Netwave given the current limitations that you mention, would it be a sound design decision to implement get_violated_limits as function returning vector or a function taking closure that would be called for each violated limit? Would such design be considered idiomatic?

Comment: @kyku I would use the dynamic dispatch in this case, sincerely. It would depend the case, but you could also create a wrapper over the vector, and implement the filtering over that, no trait ofc.

Comment: @SvenMarnach This is not a GAT problem, just that `filter()`'s callback takes `&Self::Item` and `Self::Item` is `&Limit`, so two references. The fully-specified type is `for<'b> fn(&'b &'a Limit) -> bool`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a4bfa8dba04d14d248fead0d381df42. Of course, this uses a function pointer; the real type is a closure and needs TAIT.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Indeed, this is just a double reference. The closure does not capture anything, so it coerces to a function pointer. Using `fn(&&Limit) -> bool`, this actully [works just fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0fe930100ee33ea2ebc7bed3266602da).

Comment: @SvenMarnach I added your example :)

Comment: I know it coerces, it is just not the most performant (though it'll be 99% de-virtualized). It is interesting that it doesn't require `fn(&&'a Limit) -> bool`, though.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to make this construct work, preferably without resorting to dynamic allocation?

A generic type means the *caller* decides what the type is, because `I` (the type) is an input parameter so the caller should be able to pass in whatever they want as long as it fulfills the constraints.

But that's not the case here, you give the caller no choice.

The way to give the caller no choice, but to give the *trait implementer* a choice is an associated type.

Sadly as Netwave notes, here this requires a generic associated type (as `Iterator` is generic over the `'a` lifetime), and GATs are not stable.

Two ways around that are to parameterize the trait itself, and to implement the trait for a reference rather than the type. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33756123/8182118 has examples and discussions of the possibilities.