# Non-dyn iterable?

Tags: rust

I am trying to avoid lifetimes because I still don't have a good understanding of the concept. I am reading this [wonderful article](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program) and it clarifies many misunderstandings. Although I am not sure I can solve the problem.

I know how to implement iterable collection on `dyn`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5373bb1bbe5745eb2a91a40732317d8a):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait Enumerable {
    fn elements<'a, 'b>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (i32, &String)> + 'b>
    where
        'a: 'b;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Container {
    pub map: HashMap<i32, String>,
}

impl Enumerable for Container {
    fn elements<'a, 'b>(&'a self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (i32, &String)> + 'b>
    where
        'a: 'b,
    {
        Box::new(self.map.iter().map(|el| (*el.0, el.1)))
    }
}
```

My attempt to implement the same code without `dyn`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ddabefef438952046a7daacb88e89965):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait Enumerable<'it, 'it2, It>
where
    It: Iterator<Item = &'it2 (i32, &'it String)>,
    'it: 'it2,
{
    fn elements<'a, 'b>(&'a self) -> It
    where
        'a: 'b;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Container {
    pub map: HashMap<i32, String>,
}

impl<'it, 'it2> Enumerable<'it, 'it2, core::slice::Iter<'it, (i32, &String)>> for Container {
    fn elements<'a, 'b>(&'a self) -> core::slice::Iter<'a, (i32, &'b String)>
    where
        'a: 'b,
    {
        self.map.iter().map(|el| (*el.0, el.1))
    }
}
```

I was thinking about using `impls` but there is a restriction on using it in a trait. What is wrong with the code? What other useful articles can you recommend?

Comment: Looks like you are re-implementing the `IntoIterator` trait from the standard library. But what exactly is your question? What's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: Ignoring the fact that the code does not compile, note that `trait Enumerable<'it, 'it2, It>` in the second code snippet has a very different meaning from `trait Enumerable`, since the former allows multiple `Enumerable` implementations for a single type. Is this actually what you want?

Comment: You probably want to do something like `-> impl Iterator<Item = ...>`

Comment: `impl Trait` is not allowed as the return type of a trait method. One possible solution is to use an associated type, but that may require GAT which is not stabilized yet.

Comment: Point is not reimplementing traits, but avoiding using Boxed structures and OOP. Example is oversimplified version of original problem, please don't focus on that. I've got solution. I will post it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implementing a trait function that returns generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271000/implementing-a-trait-function-that-returns-generic)

Comment: Not directly, but that is something related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution to the original problem with [GAT](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1598-generic_associated_types.html) and [TAIT](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2515-type_alias_impl_trait.html) which are not part of stable channgel for today.

Solution is

```rust
mod mod1 {

    pub trait Enumerable {
        type It<'it>: Iterator<Item = (i32, &'it String)>
        where
            Self: 'it;

        fn elements(&self) -> Self::It<'_>;
    }
}

//

impl mod1::Enumerable for Container {
    type It<'it> = impl Iterator<Item = (i32, &'it String)>;
    fn elements(&self) -> Self::It<'_> {
        self.map.iter().map(|el| (*el.0, el.1))
    }
}
```

[Full solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9ecf73ea54feda87fcbcbf5da0abb094)

There are alternative solutions, but this one works even if the trait is not part of your crate.

Also, I should note, that if possible to avoid using `lifetimes` you can implement `IntoIterator` for your `&Container`:

```rust
impl< 'it > IntoIterator for &'it Container
{
  type Item = ( &'it i32, &'it String );
  type IntoIter = std::collections::hash_map::Iter< 'it, i32, String >;
  fn into_iter( self ) -> Self::IntoIter
  {
    self.map.iter()
  }
}
```

[Full solution of a tweaked problem](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=915b2f30d96cdf9793421aca49c4fab1)

Because the lifetime is dropped that works even on stable Rust.
Most probably you want to have your own `InotIterator-like` trait, especially if there is more than a single way how can you iterate your container, but if not you can simply implement standard `IntoIterator` for reference.

Comment: You don't _have to_ use TAIT for that.

Comment: Oh, really? Why? Solution without TAIT which I had does not work in case trait is somhere else.

Comment: `type It<'it> = std::iter::Map<std::collections::hash_map::Iter<'it, i32, String>, for<'a> fn((&'a i32, &'a String)) -> (i32, &'a String)>;` or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

Apart of the fact that I don't think you need two separate lifetimes `'a` and `'b`, your first code example already looks quite promising.

Then, once you have only one lifetime, Rust can figure out lifetimes without any annotations:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait Enumerable {
    fn elements(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (i32, &String)> + '_>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Container {
    pub map: HashMap<i32, String>,
}

impl Enumerable for Container {
    fn elements(&self) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = (i32, &String)> + '_> {
        Box::new(self.map.iter().map(|el| (*el.0, el.1)))
    }
}
```

I know this is an XY-problem answer, but maybe it helps anyway. Your main reasoning behind not using `dyn` was to not deal with lifetimes, so I thought this might be relevant.